# How to backup all user data for all users in specific folders at once?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**Problem:**
New application install is forcing a complete wipe of system settings for this particular application, *Alteryx*, used for data analytics in our organization. Our desire is to create a backup of all user objects located at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Alteryx` and `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx` to a specific backup location.

Is it possible to do this in one script?

**What worked so far:**
Have tried using `robocopy` as follows, which works, but only for my user:

```
robocopy "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\\%username%\AppData\Local\Alteryx" /E /log:C:\AlteryxUserBackup\\%username%\BackupLogLocal.txt
robocopy "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" /E /log:C:\AlteryxUserBackup\\%username%\BackupLogRoaming.txt
echo Backup Complete!
```

I have experimented with for each loops on specifying a variable for the `%username%` in the folder, but no luck yet. If more explanation is needed please let me know and I can try to explain further. Only request that any solutions provided be clear to follow as I am not a programmer by nature.

Comment: FYI, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` can be used in place of `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local`. For additional environment variables, type `set` at a new open command prompt.

Comment: @Qwerty I appreciate your response but this wasn't exactly helpful in writing a script that addresses all users at once, which was what was desired. Was able to address this with a For loop and creating a variable to represent the beginning and middle of the paths. See my solution below.

Comment: Keep in mind this is the Comments section and as such, is not intended to provide Answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question with this solution:

```
for /D %D in ("C:\USERS\*") do (
    mkdir C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\AppData\Local\Alteryx
    mkdir C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx)
for /D %D in ("C:\USERS\*") do (
    robocopy /E "%~fD\AppData\Local\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\AppData\Local\Alteryx" /log:C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\BackupLogLocal.txt
)
for /D %D in ("C:\USERS\*") do (
    robocopy /E "%~fD\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" /log:C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxD\BackupLogRoaming.txt
)
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone. The `%~fd` and `%~nxD` variables were difficult to figure out but did the trick. By inverting the path order, this script can also function as an effective method of restoring objects, as well.

Comment: Three hints: __1.__ The command `robocopy` (`%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe`) automatically creates the entire directory tree to the specified destination directory on not already existing. So the first `for /D` loop is completely unnecessary. __2.__ The second and third `for /D` loop can be merged by moving the second `robocopy` command line into the command block of second `for /D` loop. __3.__ `%~fD` can be replaced by just `%D` as the full path of each found non-hidden directory in `C:\Users` is assigned to the loop variable `D` on using `"C:\USERS\*"` as directory wildcard pattern.

Comment: In other words the commands can be combined to the single command line `for /D %I in (C:\Users\*) do %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%I\AppData\Local\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxI\AppData\Local\Alteryx" /E /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:2 /W:1 >nul & %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%I\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" "C:\AlteryxUserBackup\%~nxI\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx" /E /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:2 /W:1 >nul` The usage of just `%I` (or `%D`) avoids additional file system accesses in comparison to `%~fI` (or `%~fD`). There are no log files created in this case which is faster.

Comment: It would be perhaps even better to use a batch file and check the existence of the source directory to create a backup from with an __IF__ condition like `if exist "%I\AppData\Local\Alteryx\"` for the first __ROBOCOPY__ command and `if exist "%I\AppData\Roaming\Alteryx\"` for the second __ROBOCOPY__ command.

Comment: For completeness the registry values `AppData` and `Local AppData` under registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` (current user) respectively `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` (all user accounts) define which directories are the roaming and local application data directories.